# Adding a new group for Beta testing in Google Play Developer Console

Tags: testing, google-play

I would like to use the new Alpha/Beta testing feature in Developer Console, which were recently introduced by Google. I am getting "Group not suitable" error when attempting to add a new group.

I am unable to add new users from my personal Google groups or my application Google groups.

How do I add new Group to Alpha testing without getting the "Group not suitable" error message?

Comment: is the beta testing feature, provate i.e doesnt release the app to the play store, so it can be used with apps that are still works in progress?

Comment: can you tell me who can add 1000 people to a group/community please ? I don`t want to do it one by one

Comment: @user2899094 - you can use the beta feature without publishing the application (ie. it is still not visible to the users). Note that the application should be for free, otherwise your testers must pay for it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You should provide **group email address** as the form says. For example: your_group_name@googlegroups.com

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was trying to put Google Circle name into the field rather than a new Google Group. Everything is straightforward after I created a new group.

Comment: the url to the beta testers still goes 404 :x

Comment: If you still get a 404 error - check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773341/google-play-alpha-beta-testing-link-is-broken

Please make sure that beta testers provide you with their "Android account" email - the email which they used to register their Android device. 

The most common problem is that people are not logged into their "Android account" or they give you some other personal email. If the email provided was not used for registering the Android device, they get the 404 error too.

Comment: I entered my-group-name@googlegroups.com but it keeps saying "Group not found"... Any idea please?

Answer (score 6):

My groups name is `"GRDroid Beta Testers"` so the email address must be

`grdroid-beta-testers@googlegroups.com`

[image]

Other example `"GRDroidAlphaTesters"`, the email address must be

`grdroidalphatesters@googlegroups.com`

Answer (score 6):

For those who aren't sure if they want to add a Group or a Community:

For adding a **GROUP**, use email of the group in a form **name-of-group@googlegroups.com**

For adding a **COMMUNITY**, use **URL** of that Community

Comment: wow.. i had no idea it was the URL.. why the heck don't they say so in the form?? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you create and add a Google+ COMMUNITY, not a CIRCLE. Learned that distinction the hard way.

Comment: Here's how to create a Google+ Community: https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2872671?hl=en&ref_topic=2888488  ... scroll down to middle of page, section "Create a community"

Answer (score 1):

if adding @googlegroups.com suffix doesn't work for you, you might be confused between email contact group with [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/). At first, I created an email group in my contact, and added into developer console, it kept saying that 'Group not found', that made me crazy. Ultimately, I realized that there is another Google Group on earth. :)

Comment: I entered my-group-name@googlegroups.com but it keeps saying "Group not found"... Any idea please?

Comment: Use https://groups.google.com/forum/#!overview site to create a group and try again

Comment: In the group settings, I allowed all users (Public) to publish, and then it worked... Don't know why... :-\