# Google Play Alpha/Beta testing link is broken

Tags: android, google-play, android-testing, google-play-services

I have uploaded an apk file to the Alpha Testing tab in the developer console and added a google group of my Alpha testers.
When trying to enter the generated URL I get page not found error (404).

Is it relevant to the fact that my app is still in draft mode?