# Android_Beta Testing_ The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: android, console-application, publishing, beta-testing

I've uploaded my apk and (.obb)file on the Android Developer Console to have a beta test and I've got an error when i get in to link [[https://play.google.com/apps/testing/package_name]](https://play.google.com/apps/testing/package_name%5d).

This is the error below.

"400. That's an error. The requested URL was not found on this server. That's all we know."

I've also invited in GoogleGroups so that i'm in list of tester. I'm wonder whether publishing is delayed or not. Has anyone else run into the same error?

Comment: It takes some time for google play to recognize your app, (even in beta testing). Please wait for an hour if you are sure you have done everything right while uploading. Don't panic :) I have faced the same.

Comment: @PurpleDroid I've waited for almost 4hours but in same error. I'm afraid it takes too much time :(

Comment: No. Then you must recheck email id.

Comment: @PurpleDroid I can press to participate the test when i get in the URL after login my email which is invited in google groups.

Comment: @PurpleDroid oh finally! I don't know the reason why was delayed but i can do test right now.

Comment: Congrats :) Happy coding. Must be issue of long time in uploading on google play.

Comment: @PurpleDroid Thanks a lot!! :-) oh, and do you know how to cancel or delete the apk that uploaded in beta testing.

Comment: No. As far as I know, we can't. I had also tried much :/ But in vain.

Comment: @PurpleDroid Gee.. i see. Anyway I really appreciate your help. How can i select your answer?

Comment: You will get a tick mark button on left side of answer

Comment: @PurpleDroid I got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes some time for google play to recognize your app, (even in beta testing). Please wait for an hour if you are sure you have done everything right while uploading. Don't panic :) I had faced the same. and was able to succesfully test after changing nothing, but just waiting for more than half an hour or so.

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773341/google-play-alpha-beta-testing-link-is-broken#comment31932410_16775522)

Answer (score 0):

Just add **deep link** into Invite intent

**intent.setDeepLink(Uri.parse(appLink))**

```
 Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(invitation_title)
    .setMessage(invitation_message)
    .setDeepLink(Uri.parse(appLink))
    .setCustomImage(Uri.parse(invitation_custom_image))
    .build();
```