# Can app Google App invites be used with beta apps not on the app store?

Tags: google-app-invites

Title pretty much sums this up.  Can Google app invites be used with a beta app that is not on the play store yet?

Comment: No, Beta and Alpha apps are for testers only, app-invites is for apps already in Google Play Store.

Comment: That is unfortunate as this makes it very difficult to user test before publishing.

Comment: Check this for updates in your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773341/google-play-alpha-beta-testing-link-is-broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, App Invites can be used with Alpha and Beta releases that published on Google Play.  The link to the alpha/beta build is the same as the release.  The users will have to be added to a closed alpha/beta or add themselves to an open alpha/beta before the link will work.