# Google Play App Invites failing to send with error code 13

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-app-invites

While working beautifully previously, my app-invites randomly started failing. I don't believe my code was modified at all. No idea what this error code means, either.

```
08-04 20:00:36.387   31451-2716/? E/AppInviteAgent﹕ Get suggested invitees failed due to error code: 13
08-04 20:00:54.636   31451-3312/? E/AppInviteAgent﹕ Create invitations failed due to error code: 13
```

Comment: Maybe this happens because you used the `SHA1 fingerprint` from your release key. But the build you test is signed with the android debug key. So  you can try to use `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v` to get the `debug key` and the password for default password is `android`

Comment: Why would it previously work well, then stop working?

Comment: You didn't change anything at all?

Comment: Nope. I rolled back to my previous code when I was 100% sure it was working, and it still failed with the same error code.

Comment: Maybe you need to update some library or dependence in your project

Comment: Check out the app invites code [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/appinvites), maybe they change something to new

Comment: Have you published your app and then doing testing? It might be because your app is not published on Google play: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881257/can-app-google-app-invites-be-used-with-beta-apps-not-on-the-app-store

Comment: For lost programmers, my issue was no having `com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID` set in `AndroidManifest.xml`. https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting